# Difference between chaincode and transaction processor functions?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

This might be a stupid question but I'm just wondering what the difference between chaincode and transaction processor functions is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transaction processor functions are transformed into chaincode by Hyperledger Composer. So, with Composer, the chaincode is generated for you, whereas without using Composer, you would need to author your own chaincode.